# How to fix 'An error occurred while running subprocess cordova'

Tags: cordova, compiler-errors

Most commands involving cordova error out with

`Cannot read property 'manifest' of undefined`

- I have already tried removing and re-adding the android cordova platform

`cordova platform rm android`
`cordova platform add android`

Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-facebook4" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-googleplus" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-local-notification" for android
android-sdk version check failed (/Users/ji-mac06/HybridApps/japan-info-jobs/platforms/android/cordova/android_sdk_version), continuing anyways.
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-device@2.0.2" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-device" already installed on android.
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-badge@0.8.8" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-badge" already installed on android.
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-nativestorage" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

```
           This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
```

Installing "cordova-universal-links-plugin" for android
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
Cannot read property 'manifest' of undefined

Even when adding the android platform, as you can see this error is showing up.

Comment: Can you do the following steps:

1. delete node modules folder manually
2. npm cache clear
3. npm update
4. npm install

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately. If anyone else has any ideas, please let me know. Thanks